# Links fail after AJAX call that uploads large file

Tags: ajax, file, hyperlink, upload

The links  on my page don't work after uploading a large file using AJAX. They result in the infamous error "The requested URL was rejected. If you think this is an error, please contact the webmaster. Your support ID is..." (i.e. the file upload is successful, but links subsequently fail.)

I get this behaviour after uploading a large (19 MB) file, but not after uploading a small (100 K) file, and not after uploading *no* file. If I "Clear cookies for domain", it restores the expected behaviour. (The offending cookie might be called "TS0194eee0_0".)

The errant behaviour is the same in IE 11, FireFox 40.0, and BlackBerry browsers.

What am I doing wrong? Does something persist after the AJAX call is finished that I should be clearing? (I really don't want to do a "delete cookie" hack.) JQuery is not an option. My site is serviced in a "shared host" environment, so access to php.ini is out of the question.

upload1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
function startUpload()
  {
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200)
      {alert (ajax.responseText);}
    };
  ajax.open("POST", "/test/upload2.php");
  ajax.send(new FormData(document.getElementById("form1")));
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/test/index.html">Absolute link</a><br />
  <a href="/test/index.html">Site relative link</a><br />
  <a href="index.html">Document relative link</a><br />
  <form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" /><br>
   <input type="button" value="Start Upload" onclick="startUpload()" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

upload2.php:

```
<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>
```

Update: As I suspected, deleting (expiring) the offending cookie solved the problem "for now", but for how long? I have no idea why cookie "TS0194eee0_0" is related to the problem, or if it will always have that name.

```
document.cookie = "TS0194eee0_0=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;path=/";
```